# Parallelize table construction for calculations

Tags: parallelization

I'm new to Mathematica.

My knowledge of parallel computing is very limited. I tried to figure out how to proceed using the documentation and  have found something from online help pages. My program looks as shown below:

```
Clear[tabfidC, J, B]
tabfidC = 
  ParallelTable[
    {J, B, Quiet[fidnUZST[J, B, 0.5, 0.1]]}, 
    {J, -1, 1, 0.1}, {B, 0, 2, 0.1}];

Clear[JJ,BB]
Clear[listA8]
listA8 = {{0, 0, 0}}
SetSharedVariable[listA8]
Parallelize[
  For[JJ = 1, JJ <= Dimensions[tabfidC][[1]], JJ++,
    For[BB = 1, BB <= Dimensions[tabfidC][[2]], BB++, 
      listA8 = 
        AppendTo[
          listA8, 
          {N[(JJ - 11)*1/10], N[(BB-1)*1/10], 
           1/(4*π)*
             NIntegrate[tabfidC[[JJ ,BB, 3]]*Sin[θ], {ϕ, 0, 2*π},{θ, 0, π}]}]]]]
// Quiet;

 Show[
   ListPlot3D[{Drop[listA8, 1]},
     PlotRange -> {-.05, 1.1},
     AxesLabel ->
       {Style[J, Medium, Bold, Blue],
        Style[B, Medium, Bold, Blue],
        Style[OverBar[F], Medium, Bold, Blue]},
     LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold],
     ImageSize -> Scaled[.3]]]
```

The function `fidnUZST` has been defined before. I form a table from it named `tabfidC`. Then an integral over $\theta$ and $\phi$ is performed over the the components of the table and they constitute a list named `listA8`. Finally they get plotted.

What I would like to know is how to parallelize the construction of `listA8`. I used `SetSharedVariable[listA8]`, but this does not make a difference in calculation time!

I would be grateful if you had suggestions.

Comment: Before diving into parallelization and the like, try getting into the basic Mathematica way of doing things first. `For` is not something that is normally used; instead we loop with `Do` or make lists with `Table`. `AppendTo` is a very slow way of building a list; again `Table` is preferred, or one can use `Sow`/`Reap` if one cannot know the number of elements in the table beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is somewhat obfuscated given the fact that you do not share the definition of `fidnUZST` with us. I am almost sure that you can obtain `listA8` (with only few and small further modifications) from

```
listA8 = Flatten[ParallelTable[f[J, B], {J, -1, 1, 0.1}, {B, 0, 2, 0.1}],1];
```

if you define the function `f` correctly. For example, the function `f` could look similar to

```
f[J_, B_] := {J, B/(4 π) NIntegrate[fidnUZST[J, B, 0.5, 0.1] Sin[θ], {ϕ, 0, 2*π}, {θ, 0, π}]};
```

Modifying a shared variable is a rather nontrivial task for a multicore system and needs a certain amount of overhead. Best to avoid that.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer.

Comment: I would like to share the function fidnUZST were mentioned above:

Comment: But i do not know how to attach my file

Comment: @MahmoodShamirzaie Some people use pastebin. But maybe it suffices to give a short and simple example that fits into the format of this site?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to type in this environment; I am new in this forum. Some few terms in `fidnUZST` is sent:

```
2 E^(I \[Phi])
  Cot[\[Theta]] Csc[\[Theta]] (4 ((
      E^(-5 (J + 
          2 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) (B^2 (1 + E^(
            20 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) + 
         16 (1 + E^(20 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) \[Gamma]^2 - 
         B (-1 + E^(20 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) Sqrt[
          B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2]))/(
      4 (E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) + E^(
         5 J + 10 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]) + 
         E^(-5 (J + 2 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) + 
         E^(-5 J + 10 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) (B^2 + 
         16 \[Gamma]^2)) + (
      8 (E^(-5 J + 10 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])/(
         16 + (B - Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])^2/\[Gamma]^2) + 
         E^(-5 (J + 2 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2]))/(
         16 + (B + Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])^2/\[Gamma]^2)))/(
      E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) + E^(5 J + 10 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]) + 
       E^(-5 (J + 2 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) + 
       E^(-5 J + 10 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])))^2 Cos[\[Theta]/
     2]^2 + (-(((E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) - E^(
          5 (J + 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]))) J)/(
       2 (E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) + E^(
          5 J + 10 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]) + 
          E^(-5 (J + 2 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) + 
          E^(-5 J + 10 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) Sqrt[
        b^2 + J^2])) + ((
       E^(5 (J + 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) (b - Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])^2)/(
       b^2 + J^2 - b Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]) + (
       E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) (b + Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])^2)/(
       b^2 + J^2 + b Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]))/(
      4 (E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) + E^(
         5 J + 10 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]) + 
         E^(-5 (J + 2 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) + 
         E^(-5 J + 10 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2]))) + (
      E^(5 (J + 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]))/(
       1 + (b - Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])^2/J^2) + E^(
       5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]))/(1 + (b + Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])^2/J^2))/(
      2 (E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) + E^(
         5 J + 10 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]) + 
         E^(-5 (J + 2 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) + 
         E^(-5 J + 10 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2]))))^2 Sin[\[Theta]/
     2]^2 + 2 (-(((E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) - E^(
          5 (J + 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]))) J)/(
       2 (E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) + E^(
          5 J + 10 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]) + 
          E^(-5 (J + 2 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) + 
          E^(-5 J + 10 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) Sqrt[
        b^2 + J^2])) + ((
       E^(5 (J + 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) (b - Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])^2)/(
       b^2 + J^2 - b Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]) + (
       E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) (b + Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])^2)/(
       b^2 + J^2 + b Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]))/(
      4 (E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) + E^(
         5 J + 10 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]) + 
         E^(-5 (J + 2 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) + 
         E^(-5 J + 10 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2]))) + (
      E^(5 (J + 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]))/(
       1 + (b - Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])^2/J^2) + E^(
       5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]))/(1 + (b + Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])^2/J^2))/(
      2 (E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) + E^(
         5 J + 10 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]) + 
         E^(-5 (J + 2 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) + 
         E^(-5 J + 10 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])))) (((E^(
         5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) - E^(
         5 (J + 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]))) J)/(
      2 (E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) + E^(
         5 J + 10 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]) + 
         E^(-5 (J + 2 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) + 
         E^(-5 J + 10 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) Sqrt[
       b^2 + J^2]) + ((
       E^(5 (J + 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) (b - Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])^2)/(
       b^2 + J^2 - b Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]) + (
       E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) (b + Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])^2)/(
       b^2 + J^2 + b Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]))/(
      4 (E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) + E^(
         5 J + 10 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]) + 
         E^(-5 (J + 2 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) + 
         E^(-5 J + 10 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2]))) + (
      E^(5 (J + 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]))/(
       1 + (b - Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])^2/J^2) + E^(
       5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]))/(1 + (b + Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])^2/J^2))/(
      2 (E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) + E^(
         5 J + 10 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]) + 
         E^(-5 (J + 2 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) + 
         E^(-5 J + 10 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])))) Sin[\[Theta]/
     2]^2 + (((E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) - E^(
         5 (J + 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]))) J)/(
      2 (E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) + E^(
         5 J + 10 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]) + 
         E^(-5 (J + 2 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) + 
         E^(-5 J + 10 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) Sqrt[
       b^2 + J^2]) + ((
       E^(5 (J + 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) (b - Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])^2)/(
       b^2 + J^2 - b Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]) + (
       E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) (b + Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])^2)/(
       b^2 + J^2 + b Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]))/(
      4 (E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) + E^(
         5 J + 10 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]) + 
         E^(-5 (J + 2 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) + 
         E^(-5 J + 10 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2]))) + (
      E^(5 (J + 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]))/(
       1 + (b - Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])^2/J^2) + E^(
       5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]))/(1 + (b + Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])^2/J^2))/(
      2 (E^(5 (J - 2 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2])) + E^(
         5 J + 10 Sqrt[b^2 + J^2]) + 
         E^(-5 (J + 2 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2])) + 
         E^(-5 J + 10 Sqrt[B^2 + 16 \[Gamma]^2]))))^2 Sin[\[Theta]/
     2]^2)
```

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, when I use the code you had sent, some errors appears which indicate that integration fail!